# Subscription workflow implementation in wso2 api manager 3.1.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to achieve wso2 workflow implementation on WSO2 API Manager 3.1.0, I'm unable to find the request coming to the admin portal.

can anyone please help with this?
Followed WSO2 official documentation, I tried the same in WSO2 API Manager 2.6.0 it worked fine.

**Versions using:**
WSO2 API Manager 3.1.0 &
WSO2 EI 6.5.0

Note: No log got printed in BPS server while trying this one.
logs in APIM  as follows.

```
[2020-09-21 21:40:59,988] ERROR - SubscriptionsApiServiceImpl Requested application not found
[2020-09-21 21:41:18,901] ERROR - SubscriptionsApiServiceImpl Requested application not found
[2020-09-21 21:42:12,318]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2020-09-21 21:42:12,318+0530]
[2020-09-21 21:42:12,347]  INFO - PermissionUpdater Permission cache updated for tenant -1234
[2020-09-21 21:42:12,387]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2020-09-21 21:42:12,387+0530]
[2020-09-21 21:42:13,180]  WARN - login:jag Not Retrieving Pending Tasks. Check BPS Connectivity. javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
[2020-09-21 21:42:13,346]  WARN - login:jag Not Retrieving Pending Tasks. Check BPS Connectivity. javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
```

Comment: Did you add `WSO2 EI 6.5.0` public cert to apim client-truststore?

Answer (score 3):

> "I'm trying to achieve wso2 workflow implementation on WSO2 API
> Manager 3.1.0, I'm unable to find the request coming to the admin
> portal."
>
> [2020-09-21 21:42:13,180]  WARN - login:jag Not Retrieving Pending Tasks. Check BPS Connectivity. javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
> [2020-09-21 21:42:13,346]  WARN - login:jag Not Retrieving Pending Tasks. Check BPS Connectivity. javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed

To show the task list in the Admin portal, we need to import the certificate of API Manager into the client-truststore of the EI server and also import the certificate of EI server into the client-truststore of API Manager. As per the above logs you haven't done that.

Please follow the below steps to import and export certificates among APIM and EI servers.

Paths to the directory containing the client-truststore of each product are:

1. API-M - '<API-M_HOME>/repository/resources/security'
2. EI - '<EI_HOME>/wso2/business-process/repository/resources/security

- **Export certificate from BPS and import to APIM**

  1. cd <EI_HOME>/wso2/business-process/repository/resources/security
  2. keytool -export -alias wso2carbon -keystore wso2carbon.jks -file publickeyBPS.pem
     Enter the password as wso2carbon when requested. This is the default password for keystores.
  3. cp publickeyBPS.pem <AM_HOME>/repository/resources/security
  4. cd <AM_HOME>/repository/resources/security
  5. keytool -import -alias wso2bps -file publickeyBPS.pem -keystore client-truststore.jks -storepass wso2carbon
  6. keytool -list -alias wso2bps -keystore client-truststore.jks -v
- **Export certificate from APIM and import to BPS**

  1. cd <API-M_HOME>/repository/resources/security
  2. keytool -export -alias wso2carbon -keystore wso2carbon.jks -file publickeyAPIM.pem
     Enter the password as wso2carbon when requested. This is the default password for keystores.
  3. cp publickeyAPIM.pem <EI_HOME>/wso2/business-process/repository/resources/security
  4. cd <EI_HOME>/wso2/business-process/repository/resources/security
  5. keytool -import -alias wso2apim -file publickeyAPIM.pem -keystore client-truststore.jks -storepass wso2carbon
  6. keytool -list -alias wso2bps -keystore client-truststore.jks -v